# Undefined variable in for loop pointing to another variable

Tags: javascript, html

Upon running:

```js
arr = {
  map: {
    rooms: [{}, {}]
  }
};
x = {
  entry: arr.map
};
console.log("-----");
for (i = 0; i < x.rooms.length; i++) {
  str = i.toString();
  console.log(str);
}
console.log("-----");
```

I'm met with an undefined statement.
Not sure if it's an out of scope pointer, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which line has the error?

Comment: @aryamccarthy — Why?

Comment: That code gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` because `x.rooms` isn't defined.

Comment: What is an “undefined statement”? If you get an error, please [edit] your question and show the _exact_ error message.

Comment: it should be x.entry.entry

Comment: Your original code had `x.entry.length`. Which one is it?

Comment: @techLove the line is 19

Comment: @AnilNamde You mean `x.entry.rooms`?

Comment: @Xufos oh yes it seems question is edited in meanwhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.entry` has the same value as `arr.map`, so to get at the actual rooms, you'd need `x.entry.rooms`:

```js
var arr = {
  map: {
    rooms: [{}, {}]
  }
};
var x = {
  entry: arr.map
};
console.log("-----");
for (var i = 0; i < x.entry.rooms.length; i++) {
// ------------------------^^^^^^
  var str = i.toString();
  console.log(str);
}
console.log("-----");
```

(I also added some variable declarations.)

Comment: Why there are people down voting the answers?

Comment: Why was this down-voted? *Note* please don't down-vote useful answers based on the quality of the question.

Comment: id also had this problem with an alternate more verbose example except they called on the same room but only one of the latter functions work, i'll see if i can inquire later

Answer (score 0):

Ah the question is modified. Then use `x.entry.rooms`.

---

Use `x.entry.entry` instead of `x.entry`.

When you run `x={entry:arr.map};`, you got `x.entry==arr.map`, while `arr.map.entry` is an `Array[2]`

Comment: That was true for an early version of the question. It was updated almost immediately to be `x.entry.rooms` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be i < x.entry.rooms.length, there is no rooms in 'x'.